# How can I fix this error when build a windows phone program

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7

When I built a windows phone program, There's a error message, `Syntax for "AdditionalProperties" parameter is not valid (). Correct syntax is AdditionalProperties="<name>=<value>".`, without any information of files or lines where it is.

What is the most possible reason which may cause this error?

Comment: No one can tell if you don't include the line in your code causing this error.

Comment: I have a similar problem. It seems to original from the project (Mine's an MVC 4 application). I suspect it's caused by a malformed app.config or web.config key somewhere.